# Hundreds of local loopback TIME_WAIT connections on port 7080, Plesk

Tags: linux, centos, netstat

If I run `netstat -tnep` I see about two dozen or so regulra connections, then hundreds and hundreds of local loopback conenctions to port 7080. I assume this is something to do with Plesk, but could anyone tell me if this is problematic and how to fix it.

```
Active Internet connections (w/o servers)
Proto Recv-Q Send-Q Local Address               Foreign Address             State       User       Inode      PID/Program name
... snip ...
tcp        0      0 ::ffff:127.0.0.1:7080       ::ffff:127.0.0.1:39875      TIME_WAIT   0          0          -
tcp        0      0 ::ffff:127.0.0.1:7080       ::ffff:127.0.0.1:40225      TIME_WAIT   0          0          -
tcp        0      0 ::ffff:127.0.0.1:7080       ::ffff:127.0.0.1:39980      TIME_WAIT   0          0          -
tcp        0      0 ::ffff:127.0.0.1:7080       ::ffff:127.0.0.1:39061      TIME_WAIT   0          0          -
tcp        0      0 ::ffff:127.0.0.1:7080       ::ffff:127.0.0.1:40078      TIME_WAIT   0          0          -
tcp        0      0 ::ffff:127.0.0.1:7080       ::ffff:127.0.0.1:39328      TIME_WAIT   0          0          -
tcp        0      0 ::ffff:127.0.0.1:7080       ::ffff:127.0.0.1:40242      TIME_WAIT   0          0          -
tcp        0      0 ::ffff:127.0.0.1:7080       ::ffff:127.0.0.1:39412      TIME_WAIT   0          0          -
tcp        0      0 ::ffff:127.0.0.1:7080       ::ffff:127.0.0.1:39234      TIME_WAIT   0          0          -
tcp        0      0 ::ffff:127.0.0.1:7080       ::ffff:127.0.0.1:39546      TIME_WAIT   0          0          -
tcp        0      0 ::ffff:127.0.0.1:7080       ::ffff:127.0.0.1:39696      TIME_WAIT   0          0          -
tcp        0      0 ::ffff:127.0.0.1:7080       ::ffff:127.0.0.1:39011      TIME_WAIT   0          0          -
tcp        0      0 ::ffff:127.0.0.1:7080       ::ffff:127.0.0.1:38973      TIME_WAIT   0          0          -
tcp        0      0 ::ffff:127.0.0.1:7080       ::ffff:127.0.0.1:39139      TIME_WAIT   0          0          -
tcp        0      0 ::ffff:127.0.0.1:7080       ::ffff:127.0.0.1:39846      TIME_WAIT   0          0          -
tcp        0      0 ::ffff:127.0.0.1:7080       ::ffff:127.0.0.1:40140      TIME_WAIT   0          0          -
tcp        0      0 ::ffff:127.0.0.1:7080       ::ffff:127.0.0.1:39441      TIME_WAIT   0          0          -
tcp        0      0 ::ffff:127.0.0.1:7080       ::ffff:127.0.0.1:39732      TIME_WAIT   0          0          -
tcp        0      0 ::ffff:127.0.0.1:7080       ::ffff:127.0.0.1:39491      TIME_WAIT   0          0          -
tcp        0      0 ::ffff:127.0.0.1:7080       ::ffff:127.0.0.1:39839      TIME_WAIT   0          0          -
tcp        0      0 ::ffff:127.0.0.1:7080       ::ffff:127.0.0.1:39964      TIME_WAIT   0          0          -
tcp        0      0 ::ffff:127.0.0.1:7080       ::ffff:127.0.0.1:39007      TIME_WAIT   0          0          -
tcp        0      0 ::ffff:127.0.0.1:7080       ::ffff:127.0.0.1:38914      TIME_WAIT   0          0          -
tcp        0      0 ::ffff:127.0.0.1:7080       ::ffff:127.0.0.1:40220      TIME_WAIT   0          0          -
tcp        0      0 ::ffff:127.0.0.1:7080       ::ffff:127.0.0.1:39733      TIME_WAIT   0          0          -
tcp        0      0 ::ffff:127.0.0.1:7080       ::ffff:127.0.0.1:39349      TIME_WAIT   0          0          -
tcp        0      0 ::ffff:127.0.0.1:7080       ::ffff:127.0.0.1:39273      TIME_WAIT   0          0          -
tcp        0      0 ::ffff:127.0.0.1:7080       ::ffff:127.0.0.1:38907      TIME_WAIT   0          0          -
...
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It must be your Nginx proxy forwarding requests to your Apache server. This is normal.